# Can we add "Why is it important to accept answers to questions?" to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, meta-faq

A couple of times, I've had askers comment on my answer saying that it was right, but they don't take the extra step to mark the question as answered. I'd like to have something in the FAQ I can point them to.

The text might be:

> When someone answers your question with a correct and/or useful answer, your next step should be to accept the answer that helped you the most, by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.
>
> This is important for several reasons:
>
> 1. It lets other users know that the question has been answered.
> 2. It moves the accepted answer to the top of the list of answers, so that when a user finds the question in a search, they can find the
>    answer quickly.
> 3. Finally, it gives the user who answered the question additional reputation points. This rewards the user who answered the question, allowing them to gain additional privileges on the site.

Comment: That's assuming that they read the faq

Comment: I wouldn't say "useful answer" as all answers *should* be useful to some degree. The acceptance means "this answer helped me the most".

Comment: New users are [already reminded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers) to accept answers to their answered questions.

Comment: @Sam I am, I'm looking for a way to appeal to "authority" when I leave a comment asking for the user to accept answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'd like to remind them again. :)

Comment: @ChrisF, good point, added.

Comment: In general, I dislike comments that appeal to users to accept answers to their questions.  Users are free to accept an answer or not; just as you are free to use voting for any purpose you choose (so long as you don't commit voter fraud), the OP is free to use the checkmark in any way they see fit.

Comment: I don't support point 3 at all, I think users who decline to answer questions from low-accept-rate askers are utterly wrong. However if you remove that I'll support the rest of it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're right, as usual, but I think the OP is focusing on the case where it's clear that an asker would want to accept an answer if he only knew that the feature existed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, am I not free to use comments for any purpose I choose?

Comment: @PopularDemand, that's correct.

Comment: @dpassage: No.  The purpose of comments is to clarify a post.  That's it; comments have no other sanctioned function.

Comment: @Bart, and Kate, sold, removing point 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always point people towards [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)... It has a nice authoritative [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag, and a score of 410.

Comment: I support this, provided it is only used on **questions** (not answers), where the OP has a zero accept rate.

Comment: @Popular Demand, thanks, I'll use that for now. I'd like to let the discussion go a couple more hours before I accept, though. Seems like the consensus is against adding to the main FAQ.

Comment: @dpassage Well, I gave you a workaround to what you originally suggested, so don't feel like you _have_ to accept it if you have your heart set on a site FAQ change. I'm neither for nor against your original proposal, for what it's worth.

Comment: But please, be careful about the way in which you point to that page. Whatever you do, don't say something along the lines of "Please increase your accept rate [link]".

Comment: Delegating tasks like this to the users of SO is a waste of time. People are *expected* to read the FAQ, if it's important then why not put it there? If it's not important, then why advocate posting this type of comment? See the +39 comment on the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

[Its already in the meta-faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (referenced in the [SO faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)). You can point users there if you like, but I think the fact that it is *not* already a frequently asked question should be indication enough that it's not a question new users ask, either because they don't care, or because its obvious to them.

The FAQ already goes into depth about reputation, so if they read that, they know you gain rep if they accept your answer. If they don't understand how reputation works then they probably didn't read the FAQ in the first place.