# Is there a way to get reminders/prompts to choose an answer to accept?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, accepted-answer, ios-app

I have been in the following situation a couple of times:

I post a question get some great answers - however I receive them once I have walked away from the computer and pick them up on my phone. Writing back and testing/accepting the answer this way is impractical and I would like to find a way to keep these 'to do' items somewhere prominent so I can see who I still need to pay my thanks to.

Is there something already that I'm missing?

Comment: A "Favorite" option, perhaps? You can re-visit your list of favorites later. Usually one waits 24 hours before accepting... You can also browse through your Activity/Questions tab on the mobile.

Comment: Just make a note and put it on your desktop (PC) or home screen (Mobile). You would be reminded by it. Otherwise, set a reminder in your device(s) to do so. I don't see any reminder in the SE system other than a small momentarily box that suggests you to accept an answer when you upvote it. I've more than 100 questions in Favorites, so I can't go for, neither advices it. But it may be a good option if you visit your Activity.

Comment: If you use Firefox then there is an addon named [Simple Timer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/simple-timer/). I chose a timer and it looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BHk4n.png

Comment: Considering that accepting answers on Stack Exchange is not the only activity in life that one may need reminders for... it makes more sense to use a solution that is more widely applicable than this particular use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the lack of such an alert/prompt function, you can use the search option to find

- your questions
- that have at least one answer
- is not yet accepted

[`user:me is:q hasaccepted:no answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A816620+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1)

(for the example to work I used the questions from [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) on Stack Overflow)

You can read more about the search options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) or by clicking the *Advanced Search Tips* link on the right of the search page.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no feature explicitly designed to maintain a prominent list of questions for which you have not accepted an answer, no. The closest you would come is by favoriting the question or simply going back and reviewing the list of questions you've asked, [as Deer Hunter suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261732/is-there-a-way-to-get-reminders-prompts-to-choose-an-answer-to-accept#comment853390_261732), but neither of those will produce a prompt or reminder without you deciding to go back to those lists first. We do have [a prompt for some cases when the author attempts to upvote a answer to their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777), but that's only if you navigate back to the question on your own. Lastly, there are some cases where the questions list on your profile will prompt you to consider putting a bounty on a question or accept an answer for a question, but there's currently no way to filter to just those questions or to receive more active notifications about them.

Answer (score 3):

On the [questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/293374/bendy?tab=questions) in the user profile, (I chose yours here), I was recently greeted (in mine) by a

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this
>   question?

which reminds that the question is still open.

Apart from that, there is always *the status of the question*. Is it still open, or have you accepted an answer? (Maybe in combination with the favorite status, if you choose to abuse this option)

TL;DR: You might wish **use the question status** (accepted/open) to remind you if you still need to act on this.