# Accept button is not clear to new users so they are less likely to accept an answer

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, accepted-answer

On every question that I answer where a user has less than a 100 rep I tell them to accept or optionally up vote my answer.  If I don't do this, they *might* up vote me but if they have less than 15 rep it'll tell them they can't vote and might do nothing at all.

I'm certain you can run reports on first time users to see their behavior compared to users with more than 100 rep.

Lastly, people do not even know there is a checkbox there or what it does (refer to the screenshot).  You could have a giant hover box or some sort of message that they should accept the post if it's their first time voting.  Please enhance your UI and educate new users better since it is not obvious to them.

This may be a dupe but I'm okay with that.  There has to be a better way to teach users so people like me don't clutter the site with pointless 'please accept an answer' comments.

Screenshot:

[image: I like burritos]]

And another screenshot:

[image: and sushi]

Comment: *Lastly, people do not even know there is a checkbox there or what it does (refer to the screenshot).* I don't think this happens in more than a few isolated cases. Can you prove that this is a large-scale problem?

Comment: Of course not.  Run a report on the data. I only have anecdotal evidence right now haha

Comment: [here is some data](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417474#graph) notice that this represents reputation divided by 10. Feel free to fork.

Comment: I seem to remember that if you upvote an answer on your question it displays a pop up which suggests you accept it if it helped you.

Comment: @angussidney that may be true but looking at the data, it appears that is not good enough

Comment: @rene Can the report also query comments to see if someone said "accept my answer" or similar ?

Comment: @angussidney, I think you're right, but if you don't have enough rep to upvote I don't think it suggests accepting the answer.  Which would be odd, since these low-rep users are the ones who most need the education, but from the screenshot above and similar comments I've seen it seems to be the case.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

I have also seen these types of comments many times.

Since the "upvote" buttons tend to be more easily understood than the checkmark (i.e. most users who comment "How do I accept?" also mention that they have attempted to upvote, as in the screenshot above), I would recommend the following solution be implemented:

**When a user who doesn't have sufficient reputation to upvote clicks the upvote button on an answer *to a question he has asked*, the popup message should educate him about answer *acceptance*.**

The exact wording of the popup message could be discussed but something like (in very rough form): "Once you reach 15 reputation you will be able to upvote.  However—if this answer solved your problem or answered your question fully, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark."  Something like that.

The point is that it would be triggered by a low-rep question author clicking the upvote button on an answer they've received.

<sub>Or does that exist already?</sub>

Comment: I think it should display if the user is hovering their mouse over the up vote button rather then waiting until they click and receive an error they may or may not read.